# Why miners are not picking my arbitrage trading bot transaction on ethereum.?

Tags: solidity, flashbots, mev

Miners not picking my arbitrage trading bot transaction that is sent to miners directly using relay.flashbot.net rpc. And we are also giving reward through block.coinbase.transfer() function and also paying high gas fee.

Comment: Are you not tipping enough? can i get a look at the Contract

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start is to find the competitor's transaction and reverse engineer what they did differently. You can compare gas used, gas price, transaction fees, how much of their profit did they directly transfer to the miner...

There's a number of factors that could be at play here, but the most logical step is starting with why exactly did someone else get the reward you wanted?